# Accept double type only in a given format as method parameter in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any possibility to force a parameter tpye to accept only a given format and not only in runtime?

What I mean, for instance I have a method:

```
public void AcceptTest(double version)
{

}
```

This method will accept 1.0 but 1.00, 1.0067 and so on.
How can I solve to accept only x.y and nothing else but without check it from code by String.Format or something else.
So I don't even give the possibility to write an unacceptable format in the code editor also.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you define an *"unacceptable format"*? All these values are valid `double`

Comment: You can't. For the compiler a `double` is a `double` is a `double`... For the compiler there is no difference between 1.0, 1.01, 1.001...

Comment: `System.Double` has no format, just a value. Maybe you can use `System.Version`.

Comment: you can, if you make your own

Comment: Have a look at `Version` class instead of `double`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can you define what you would expect for a double other than `x.y` the only other possible value for a double would be just `x` with no decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is not quite clear, and depending on it any number of answer are possible. Including several that read "you are on a poor track" and "that is impossible".

You can not with Double. Double is defined as a number with a high possibility for decimal places. Every number from it's range is viable, both at compile and runtime.

You could round it automatically, wich might be considered poor behavior.
You could check if the "input" is the same as the "input rounded to the 1st decimal digit" (to see if the other party did the rounding for your).

Note that float imprecision will still result in ending up with wierd decimal places. This is a inherent part of floating point numbers:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Some implementations of decimal allow you to specify how many digits after comma to allow. But the [.NET one is not among them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx). At least it avoids the decimal imprecision by lowering the value range.

You could just store as (unsigned) integer. Setting the comma during output would become a display side thing. Maybe make your own structure for this so you can provide your own ToString().

Hop that helps, but calrification would be nessesary. In particular your goal and intention. or the specific problem that makes such a limitation nessesary.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments. I got many useful informations. The purpose of my question has two main points, the first is the simplicity. If I create a custom class to define the version number that makes one plus class. May I can use integer but it will cause readability issue on developer side. If I dfine it as an integer, everyone will only see: AcceptTest(1) which is definitely more difficult to read than AcceptTest(1.0). That's the only two point why I asked my question, simplicity and readability.

Comment: Oh, it is for Versioning. My first guess would have been string. But looking for it, apparently .NET has a class for it. A simple "4 Int, sealded" case:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx
You could add a custom parse function to your version (or add Parsing as Extension method to that one).